# how to return a list inside a function without commas or [ ]

Tags: python, list, function, format

I am trying to make a program using Python that returns the variable heights without the commas or [ ] like I did for my printList function. However, I cannot do this like i did in my printList function without printing the variable, which I don't want to do.

Here is my code:
The problem is occurring in the nextYear function.

```
def printList(heights):
    print(*heights, sep = " ")

def findAverage(heights):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        total += heights[i]
        i += 1
    average = total / len(heights)
    return ("{:.2f}".format(average))

def findSmallest(heights):
    smallest = heights[0]
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        if heights[i] < smallest:
            smallest = heights[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    return smallest

def findLargest(heights):
    largest = heights[0]
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        if heights[i] > largest:
            largest = heights[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    return largest

def nextYear(heights):
    for i in range(len(heights)):
        heights[i] += 5
        i += 1
    heights = (*heights, sep = " ")
    return heights

#main routine

heights = [33, 45, 23, 43, 48, 32, 35, 46, 48, 39, 41]
printList(heights)
print("Average is " + str(findAverage(heights)))
print("Smallest is " + str(findSmallest(heights)))
print("Largest is " + str(findLargest(heights)))
print("Predicted heights after a year")
printList(nextYear(heights))
```

Expected output:

```
33 45 23 43 48 32 35 46 48 39 41
Average is 39.36
Smallest is 23
Largest is 48
Predicted heights after a year
38 50 28 48 53 37 40 51 53 44 46
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Get rid of `heights = (*heights, sep = " ")` in `nextYear`...

Comment: You *really* need to understand the difference between *returning* and printing something. They aren't the same thing at all. You cannot return a list "without the commas or [ ]" None of those things are *in the list*. They are part of a way a list is printed. It's not clear what you want or why.

Comment: Also, you don't' return variables, you return *objects*. That may sound pedantic, but you really have to understand these points before moving forward, or else you are building up a house of cards in your knowledge. What *object* do you want to return from `nextYear`?

Comment: I want to return the new heights that have had 5 added to each of the elements in heights separated by only spaces

Comment: @coder1234 so, you want a *list*? Again, what **object**, exactly, do you want to return?

Comment: heights is the name of the variable but I could name it new_heights so it wouldn't be as confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To join list items into a single string, use `join`.

```
    heights = " ".join(str(h) for h in heights)
```

`heights` is now a single string with all of the values separated by a single space. You can print it as-is. Omit `printList` and use

```
print(" ".join(str(h) for h in heights))
```

EDIT: There are some more things to note. In `nextYear`, one does not need to increment `i`; that is the job of the `for` loop in python. It could be a nicer transform with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions), which are worth looking into:

```
next_heights = [h + 5 for h in heights]
```

in `findLargest`, you can check the [`max` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max). There are also `min` and `sum` which could help here.

Using `.format` or f-strings is almost always preferred to concatenation.

```
print("Largest is {}".format(findLargest(heights))
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: def nextYear(heights):      *enter*                       
        next_heights = [h + 5 for h in heights]         *enter*              
        print(" ".join(next_heights))'''     *enter*

Comment: You're right, the list does need to have string members initially that way. Updated. You can cast them all in a comprehension as you print.